# How do I roll data within groups in a dataframe?

Tags: python, data-preprocessing, pandas

The original dataframe is like df1.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'group': [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2], 'in': list(range(1,11)), 'out': [0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1]})
df1
```

The output I want is like df2. I want to add a new column which rolls the data in column 'in'.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'group': [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2], 'in': list(range(1,11)), 'out': [0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1], 'in_roll': [4,5,1,2,3,9,10,6,7,8]})
df2
```

[image]

I don't know how to do this. I can only use np.roll or groupby to get df3 and df4, which are not what I exactly want. Anyone know how to derive df2? Thanks!

```
df3 = df1
df3['in_roll'] = np.roll(df3['in'], shift=2)
df3
```

```
df4 = df1
df4['in_roll'] = df4.groupby('group')['in'].shift(2)
df4
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
df1['in_roll'] = df1.groupby(by= 'group')['in'].transform(lambda x: numpy.roll(x, 2))
```